# Successfully added .active state to menu nav, but not active color

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

My main navigation menu is controlled by WordPress, as found below.
I wanted to change the active state when someone clicks a link in the menu, by creating adding: **background-color** and **color** to style it.

Whilst clicking a menu item has successfully shown the background-color change, the original text color has not changed to the active state.

**Header.php**

```
    <?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'primary' ) ) : ?>
        <nav class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
            <?php
                // Primary navigation menu.
                wp_nav_menu( array(
                    'menu_class'     => 'nav-menu',
                    'theme_location' => 'primary',
                ) );
            ?>
        </nav><!-- .main-navigation -->
    <?php endif; ?>
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('ul li a').click(function(){
    jQuery('li a').removeClass("active");
    jQuery(this).addClass("active");
  });
});
```

**CSS (snippet)**

```
a {
background-color: transparent;
}

.active{
   background-color: #242424;
  color: #ffffff;
}

  a:active,
   a:hover {
   outline: 0;
     }

.sidebar .main-navigation a {
display: block;
padding: 12px 0;
position: relative;
text-decoration: none;
   }

.sidebar .main-navigation ul {
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
  }

  .sidebar .main-navigation ul ul {
display: none;
margin-left: 12px;
  }

  .sidebar .main-navigation ul .toggled-on {
display: block;
  }

   .sidebar .main-navigation li {
border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
position: relative;
   }

  .sidebar .main-navigation .nav-menu {
border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
 }

   .sidebar .main-navigation .nav-menu > ul > li:first-child,
   .sidebar .main-navigation .nav-menu > li:first-child {
border-top: 0;
  }
   .sidebar .main-navigation .menu-item-has-children > a {
padding-right: 48px;
  }
```

***Navigation menu rendered html is:-***

```
<button id="sidebar-toggle" class="sidebar-toggle"></button>
<nav class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
    <div class="menu-top-menu-container">
        <ul id="menu-top-menu" class="nav-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-18" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-home menu-item-18"><a href="http://example.com/">Home</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-19" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-8 current_page_item menu-item-19 active "><a href="http://example.com/about">About</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-21" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-21"><a href="http://example.com/contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav><!-- .main-navigation -->
```

Comment: You need to make the rule more specific so that it overrides any other previously set on the element, eg `#container .foo.bar .active { color: #FFF; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your HTML provided by you, you have to do it like below:-

```
.main-navigation ul > li.active{ background-color: #242424;}
.main-navigation ul > li.active >a{color: #ffffff; /*if not worked then add !important and check once*/}
```

***Example:-***

```css
.main-navigation ul > li.active{ background-color: #242424;}
.main-navigation ul > li.active >a{color: #ffffff; /*if not worked then add !important and check once*/}
```

```html
<button id="sidebar-toggle" class="sidebar-toggle"></button>
<nav class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
  <div class="menu-top-menu-container">
    <ul id="menu-top-menu" class="nav-menu">
      <li id="menu-item-18" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-home menu-item-18"><a href="http://example.com/">Home</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-19" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-8 current_page_item menu-item-19 active "><a href="http://example.com/about">About</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-21" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-21"><a href="http://example.com/contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav><!-- .main-navigation -->
```

Comment: Hi @Alive to Die, I already tried your option, unfortunately it has not worked, hence posting my menu. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @MichaelMHL  check my edited answe. I have changed according to you html

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and your support on my issue. That worked out without requiring !important. Many thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to write any jquery code to set active class on wordpress navigation. Bydefault Wordpress give `current_page_item` class for active nav item, You can use following CSS for this.

```
.current_page_item {
   background-color: #242424;
   color: #ffffff;
}
```

**OR**

```
.current_page_item a {
   background-color: #242424;
   color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Super User, I implemented your CSS, and whilst it does take effect, the text color has not changed, only the background color. Could you be able to further advise?

Comment: @MichaelMHL You can use `.current_page_item a` selector

Answer (score 0):

Please add the following class to your css and check it

```
.active{
   background-color: #242424;
  color: #ffffff !important;
}
```